# world ->setContactListener (contactListener)? my app crashes when i write this line

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

When i write this line my application crashes

```
world ->setContactListener (contactListener)
```

Error message is in

```
void b2World::SetContactListener(b2ContactListener* listener)
{
    m_contactManager.m_contactListener = listener;    //EXE_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

Please help me i want to use contactlistener for Collision detection...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that m_contactManager is not set if your program is failing at that line.

Comment: check in debugger that m_contactManager is not NULL before this call

Answer (score 0):

did you remember to initialize `contactListener`? If you try to use an uninitialized pointer in the call to `setContactListener`, you'll get a BAD_ACCESS. Make sure you've got a line like this before the call:

```
ContactListener *contactListener = new ContactListener();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
_contactListener = new MyContactListener();
world->SetContactListener(_contactListener);
```

To write this code, after word is created.

Reason for crash: World is not created but you setContactListener to world, thatsway your app got crash.
I think this helpful for you...